What should the android foregroundServiceType be?
I created an app to manage the clipboard
This time, I plan to update the SDK version to 34.
Among the app features, there is a function that displays the contents of the clipboard when notification is always displayed and the notification is clicked.
However, starting from version 34, the foregroundServiceType must be specified, but I do not know what the foregroundServiceType should be.
Can I set the foregroundServiceType to dataSync?

Why do you need a service to just show a notification?

Definition:

The term "foregroundServiceType" is an Android concept that refers to
the type of 'foreground service' that a user has explicitly started or
been requested to start by an "app". It is a critical part of the
Android foreground service management system. A foreground service is
a service that continues running and notifies the user that it is
running, even when the user is not actively using the app. This type
of service requires a notification to be shown to the user (like e.g when you connect your device USB device its shown in Notification Screen), and the
user can manage it at any time.

Maybe the service you are using can "drain" the battery deliberately if its continuously used and the user must be "notified" of such use so it's need to be displayed on "Notification Screen",
Since android 14+ have made it mandatory to set forgroundServiceType.
I have given a Medium link where they've mentioned about the details.
Here-
Medium-ForegroundServiceType
